# Details of compiling out-of-tree drivers for Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I am trying to compile a WiFi driver for an oldish (3.18.29) kernel.

Processor is an MT7628 (mips), board is a VoCore2.

I have the kernel correctly configured and built in `/home/mcon/vocore/kernel`.
As I am cross-compiling I also need to give a pointer to my cross-toolchain.

```
mcon@cinderella:~/vocore/kernel$ make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=/home/mcon/vocore/Buildroot/toolchain/host/bin/mipsel-linux- 
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc.o
  ...
  IHEX    firmware/edgeport/down3.bin
  IHEX2FW firmware/whiteheat_loader.fw
  IHEX2FW firmware/whiteheat.fw
  IHEX2FW firmware/keyspan_pda/keyspan_pda.fw
  IHEX2FW firmware/keyspan_pda/xircom_pgs.fw
mcon@cinderella:~/vocore/kernel$ make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=/home/mcon/vocore/Buildroot/toolchain/host/bin/mipsel-linux- modules_prepare
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
net/sched/Kconfig:43: warning: menuconfig statement without prompt
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
```

Diver is taken from [here](https://github.com/saviourxx/openwrt_dl/raw/master/mt7628-p4rev-120395.tar.bz2) and unpacked in `/home/mcon/vocore/mt7628-p4rev-120395`

I had to add a symlink because `Makefile` looks in `../mt_wifi` and not in `../src` if not compiling for OpenWRT.

Anyways compilation doesn't seem to do anything:

```
mcon@cinderella:~/vocore/mt7628-p4rev-120395/build$ make -C /home/mcon/vocore/kernel M=$(pwd) CROSS_COMPILE=/home/mcon/vocore/Buildroot/toolchain/host/bin/mipsel-linux- ARCH=mips
make: Entering directory '/home/mcon/vocore/linux-3.18-vocore2'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
make: Leaving directory '/home/mcon/vocore/linux-3.18-vocore2'
```

I have been unable to start kernel configuration for module:

```
mcon@cinderella:~/vocore/mt7628-p4rev-120395/build$ make -C /home/mcon/vocore/kernel M=$(pwd) CROSS_COMPILE=/home/mcon/vocore/Buildroot/toolchain/host/bin/mipsel-linux- ARCH=mips menuconfig
make: Entering directory '/home/mcon/vocore/linux-3.18-vocore2'
make: *** No rule to make target 'menuconfig'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/home/mcon/vocore/linux-3.18-vocore2'
```

... and I also tried to manually add relevant configuration variables to `.config` and/or command-line, but they seem to be completely ignored.

I am obviously missing some needed step, but I'm unable to understand what.

Comment: *.config* doesn't know anything about out-of-tree files.

Comment: @0andriy: That I guessed. How should I configure my out-of-tree driver?

Comment: By the line `obj-$(...) += foo.o`. Whatever the level your object falls in will be the configuration for your driver.